# Не могу понять почему в pycharm не работают срезы

Tags: pycharm

Цель совершить в pycharm примитивный срез.

Вот код, который я вбил в pycharm.

```
squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
squares[-3:]
print(squares)
```

Желаемый результат:[9, 16, 25]
Выдает ошибку "Statement seems to have no effect" И исходный список без изменений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не присваиваете какой-либо переменной этот срез.

```
squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
squares2 = squares[-3:]
print(squares2)  # [9, 16, 25]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Разве это обязательно?
тогда почему такой код проходит в "python.exe". Темный экран который

Comment: потому что срез создаёт новый список, а не изменяет уже существующий
в python.exe на экран выводится этот новый список, но т.к. никакой переменной вы его не присваиваете, после этого он не сохраняется

Comment: `тогда почему такой код проходит в "python.exe".` Потому что в том случае вы работаете в режиме диалога (REPL — read-eval-print loop)

Comment: Я то думал что с pycharm проблемы.
Всем спасибо за ответы, с вашей помощью я разобрался!